# Toast function for tvOS in swift

Tags: swift, toast, tvos

I am new to Xcode and tvOS. I am making a video app, which requires me to have an Android like toast message while the video is being played (basically on the video).

I came across many github repos for iOS, which I tried implementing but was unsuccessful in it. Any help is much appreciated! thanx

Comment: Welcome to SO and a few tips when posting a question; Always describe what you have tried, describe the behaviour you are seeing that is wrong, where possible supply source code of the work you have done and if your issue is with a third party project then reference said project.

Comment: Hey, really sorry guys, always have been a great fan of stack overflow. tvOS is relatively new and hence wanted a quick answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this project which implements a toast view for tvOS: https://github.com/movielala/TVOSToast
Maybe this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, you should accept the answer, this way people coming here from a search can easily see which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

To play videos, look into either MPMoviePlayerViewController (which is easier but less customizable), or AVPlayer, which is more customizable.
To add an overlay on top of the playing video, you can simply add a UIView to the top of your view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little vague so I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. But if you want a custom overlay on a video, you can put a UIView on top of the video and customize it however you like.

Comment: You should always comment first on a question in order to clarify exactly what OP is asking before answering - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11322244).